# Connecting to RFID with LLRP

Tags: java, socket.io, rfid

I have A UHF Passive RFID Reader, The reader is come with C# SDK.dll and it meet international ISO 18000\EPC G2 standards.

The problem is when I try to connect to reader as TCP Client using the SDK provided, I am able to connect to the reader but when I am connecting to reader through LLRP interface, I am not able to connect

I am developing java RFID application. but solution can be from other lang too.

below is the code for more details

```
import org.llrp.ltk.net.LLRPConnection;
import org.llrp.ltk.net.LLRPConnectionAttemptFailedException;
import org.llrp.ltk.net.LLRPConnector;
import org.llrp.ltk.net.LLRPEndpoint;
import org.llrp.ltk.types.LLRPMessage;

public class LLRPEndPoint implements LLRPEndpoint {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LLRPEndPoint endpoint = new LLRPEndPoint();
        }

        public LLRPEndPoint() {
            LLRPConnection connection = new LLRPConnector(this, "192.168.0.100",5000);
            try {
                ((LLRPConnector) connection).connect();
            } catch (LLRPConnectionAttemptFailedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
         @Override
        public void errorOccured(String message) {
             System.out.println(message);
        }
        @Override
        public void messageReceived(LLRPMessage message) {
            System.out.println(message.getResponseType());
        }
}
```

when I run this program I am getting **LLRPConnectionAttemptFailedException**. I have reader running on IP 192.186.0.100 on port 5000. I verified that with the SDK provided Reader

In short I just want a way to work with reader with LLRP.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: *"Urgent:"*  Too localized!   In future please consider either leaving your time constraints or hiring a consultant.

Comment: You should tell more details about the problem you are facing to get an answer.

Comment: apologies for my language and thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing first.
**Is your RFID reader support LLRP?**

- ***If not*** then your program is at a dead-end no more possibilities ask for vendor to support you.
- ***If yes*** then you need to connect with the RFID reader using LLRP Client instead of LLRP Endpoint.
- The default port number for LLRP is **5084(non-secured)**,**5085(secured over TLS)**.
- **IN LLRP Client mode** you just need to provide the **IP address** of the reader and **port no** of the reader.
- **IN LLRP Endpoint mode** you just need to provide the **system IP address** and **system port no** on whatever you want to listen.
- Both communications are different.
  LLRP client is application initiated like your program.
  LLRP Endpoint is reader initiated like your reader will initiate the connection.
  Both will work over the TCP layer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code samples here: http://learn.impinj.com/articles/en_US/RFID/Creating-RFID-Applications-with-Java/

This post will show you how to create a Java LTK "Hello World" application that reads tags.

Comment: Link is dead in 2016. No surprise, but still.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the reader RFID has the service llrp stopped for default

You need to activate the service llrp.

Answer (score 0):

The  Java LTK is an open source software project that enables RFID application development on readers that support LLRP. Although the Java LTK isn't an Impinj software product, it works very well with the Speedway Revolution reader. This post will show you how to create a Java LTK "Hello World" application that reads tags:

https://support.impinj.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201883748-How-do-I-create-RFID-applications-with-Java-

Comment: can't open this page.

Answer (score -1):

You should have the LLRP server running on the device. Device may have a web interface, you can possibly check the status of the LLRP server from the web interface.

The default port number for LLRP is 5084.